# Check if user's input number is positive or negative, and give error it it is negative

Tags: lua

I am trying to create a program that takes the user's input width and height and outputs area and perimeter of a rectangle. I also want the program to check if the user puts a positive or negative value for either the width or height. If the user puts in a negative value for either I want it to display an error. This is what I have so far but it kinda just skips passed and still calculates.

```
local width, height, area, perimeter

-- intro text and user inputs
print("Welcome to the Rectangle Area & Perimeter Calculator")

print("Enter Rectangle Width")
width = io.read("n")
if width <0 
then print "Error: Please enter a positive value for width"
end

print("Enter Rectangle Height")
height = io.read("n")
if height <0
then print "Error: Please enter a positive value for height"
end 

--Calculator
area = width * height
print("The area of the rectangle is ", area)
perimeter = 2 * (width + height)
print("The perimeter of the rectangle is ", perimeter)
```

Comment: `if width <0 then error "Please enter a positive value for width" end`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit 2 : you can use `repeat`  `until`  loop for this , so the block of code will be **repeated until** the user input number is **positive**  , try below code

```
local width, height, area, perimeter

-- intro text and user inputs
print("Welcome to the Rectangle Area & Perimeter Calculator")

repeat
print("Enter Rectangle Width")
width = io.read("n")
  if(width < 0)
    then print("error : enter a positive value")
  end
until width > 0 

repeat
print("Enter Rectangle Height")
height = io.read("n")
  if height <0
    then print "Error: Please enter a positive value for height"
  end  
until height > 0 

--Calculator
area = width * height
print("The area of the rectangle is ", area)
perimeter = 2 * (width + height)
print("The perimeter of the rectangle is ", perimeter)
```

Comment: Lua 5.3 does not require it. `Option names in io.read do not have a starting '*' anymore. For compatibility, Lua will continue to accept (and ignore) this character.`

Comment: using return doesnt re-do the

     print("Enter Rectangle Width")
     width = io.read("n")

I want it to keep re-asking the user to enter the width if they keep inputing a negative number. if they enter a positive number, have the program move forward to the next code: 

     print("Enter Rectangle Height")
     height = io.read("n")